# How can I do a Tukey's HSD test on this data?

Tags: r, tukey

I am trying to perform a Tukey's HSD test or an LSD test on my data. I have two factors, Collection (2 treatments) and Irrigation (5 treatments), and want to do the test on the Sucrose responses from each combination, so 10 total treatments.

Data:

```
structure(list(Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), Irrigation = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Rate1", "Rate2", "Rate3", "Rate4", 
"Rate5"), class = "factor"), meanSuc = c(0.585416666666667, 0.5032, 
0.61375, 0.602775, 0.688466666666667, 0.545133333333333)), row.names = 
 c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(Collection = structure(1:2, .Label = c("1", 
"2"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:5, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = 
c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Attempt at combining treatments into a column and using Agricolae to perform test:

```
Tukey_data <- dataAvgSucCI %>% 
  mutate(Tukey_ID = paste(Collection, Irrigation, sep="_"))
TukeyAov <- aov(meanSuc ~ Tukey_ID,Tukey_data)
HSD.test(TukeyAov, "Tukey_ID", group=TRUE)
```

Error message:

> Error in if (pvalue[k] <= 0.001) sig[k] <- "***" else if (pvalue[k] <=
>       : 
>         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>       In addition: Warning message:
>       In qtukey(1 - alpha, ntr, DFerror) : NaNs produced

**How should I edit my code to make it work?**

Or would I be better off writing something entirely different?

Comment: You have to convert Tukey_ID to a factor `aov(meanSuc ~ as.factor(Tukey_ID), data = Tukey_data)`

Comment: When I do this, I don't get an error message, but I get the response "NULL". Any idea why that's the case?

Comment: Thanks for the response! What you said makes sense, and I updated my code to reflect that. This is how it looks now `Tukey_data <- data %>%
  mutate(Tukey_ID = paste(Collection, Irrigation, sep="_"))
; TukeyAov <- aov(Suc ~ as.factor(Tukey_ID), data = Tukey_data)HSD.test; (TukeyAov, "Tukey_ID", group=TRUE)` however, I still get the "NULL" response unfortunately. Do you have any additional suggestions? Thanks again!

Comment: Your data is rank deficient. There are too few members per group in `Tukey_ID`.

Answer (score 0):

The data have to look like this (One way ANOVA):

```
Collection =  rep(1:2, times = 1, each = 5)
Irrigation = rep(1:5, times = 2, each = 1)
meanSuc = rnorm(10, mean = 0, sd = 1)

d = data.frame(Collection, Irrigation, meanSuc)

fit = aov(meanSuc ~ as.factor(Collection), data=d)

TukeyHSD(fit)
```

or Two way ANOVA:

```
fit2 = aov(meanSuc ~ as.factor(Collection) + as.factor(Irrigation), data = d)

TukeyHSD(fit2)
```

I think you like to perform a two way ANOVA. Like AkselA said, there is no variation in your target variable (meanSuc), If you perform a one way ANOVA like you did.

Comment: They're using `HSD.test()` from `agricolae`.